# crash (or automatic restart) of service

Tags: android

I've a service that runs after the Android devices boots up. This executes two notifications every day. But I've a problem: It looks like the the service crashes or automatically restarts. Also the notifications are not executed at the specified time. How can I fix this? Sometime I see the toast `Service Created` and `Service Started`. Thanks!

The code:

```
public class UnUsedService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 05); //midday
        cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
        cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);//8pm for example
        cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService  (Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(),cal2.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your notices need to run at a particular time, you should be using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule them. This gets retained by Android, so that your service is free to be killed and the alarm will restart it when necessary.

It sounds like you're currently letting your service run 24/7 just so that it can do something twice a day; this is being a bad Android citizen! Using the `AlarmManager` instead will fix your problem and also let you stop wasting resources.

Comment: mhmh..my service runs outside my app. When an user reboot own device, could not open app. If a user does not open app how notification runs? I need of a service. Or mistake something? thanks.

Comment: If your service is being started (through BOOT_COMPLETED or some other means), the service can install the AlarmManager.

Comment: My service starts with BOOT_COMPLETED. How "install" alarmmanager by service? Is not same thing of my code? thanks.

Comment: Read the AlarmManager documentation and examples. You can set up your alarm from your service. "Is not same thing of my code" -- then what is it? If you write the service, it's your code. You can have your service start when BOOT_COMPLETED happens as you are, but you cannot prevent Android from killing it. AlarmManager _is_ how you schedule it to be restarted later (but if you know your service is finished until a long time passes, you _should_ not wait for Android to kill you, just stop your service voluntarily since your alarm will restart it).